# How do I calculate the mean of this quantity?

Tags: statistics

Let's say I have an array of numbers that have a specific order, say:

$$x_1, x_2, x_3, \cdots x_n$$

**Problem:** How do I calculate the mean of $\Delta x$, where 
$\Delta x = x_{n+1}-x_n$
?

At first glance it might seem trivial:
$$\langle \Delta x \rangle = \frac1{n-1}\sum_{i=0}^n (x_{i+1}-x_i)$$
But let's look at an example. Suppose that I have the following four numbers:
$$1,5,8,11$$
Using the equation above would mean:
$$\langle \Delta x \rangle = \frac13\big[(5-1)+(8-5)+(11-8)\big] = \frac1310 \approx 3.33$$
But I could also sum the terms:
$$\frac{11-5}{2} \quad ; \frac{8-1}{2}$$
Which would mean:
$$\frac15\bigg[(5-1)+(8-5)+(11-8)+3+\frac72\bigg]=\frac{33}{10} = 3.3$$
Which is a different result. For me it seems that the first result is correct, because it agrees with the definition of mean.

**Question:** Which one is correct, and why does taking the two extra terms I proposed gives an incorrect result?

Comment: I don't even understand the second approach.  Why would that calculate something called a mean?

Comment: $(11-5)/2$ is the average of $(11-8)$ and $(8-5)$. Similarly, $(8-1)/2$ is the average of $(8-5)$ and $(5-1)$. Note that $(8-5)$ appears in both of these averages. So, your second approach is weighting $(8-5)$ more than the other differences.

Comment: Note that $\sum_{i=1}^n(x_{i+1}-x_i)$ is just $x_n-x_1$. Are you sure this is what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first attempt is correct.

Note that you can simplify the process by telescoping your sum $$ \sum _{i=0}^{n-1} (x_{i+1}-x_i) = x_n-x_0$$ Thus your mean is simply $$ \frac {x_n-x_0}{n-1}$$